# Error running Gradle on flutter with Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, dart, flutter

i have been having this issue on flutter with Visual Studio Code during the debugging session for more than a week now, have tried all possible answers i saw but it's still now working and i need to run my app to see my progress.

if there's any alternative on how to run the app with please kindly provide just to run the app for now.

Am suppose to know if i'm going good or lacking behind my classes.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO Camon CX in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\IB\Desktop\Android\myapp\berry_networks\Dart test\Scaffold\intro_to_scaffold\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.2.1/builder-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.2.1/builder-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.2.1/crash-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.2.1/crash-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.2.1/lint-gradle-api-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.2.1/lint-gradle-api-26.2.1.jar'.
            > No such host is known (dl.google.com)
   > Could not download gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.2.1/gradle-api-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.2.1/gradle-api-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download databinding-compiler-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.2.1/databinding-compiler-common-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.2.1/databinding-compiler-common-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.2.1/manifest-merger-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.2.1/manifest-merger-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.2.1/sdk-common-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.2.1/sdk-common-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.2.1/builder-test-api-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.2.1/builder-test-api-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.2.1/ddmlib-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.2.1/ddmlib-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.2.1/sdklib-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.2.1/sdklib-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.2.1/layoutlib-api-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.2.1/layoutlib-api-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.2.1/dvlib-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.2.1/dvlib-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.2.1/repository-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.2.1/repository-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.2.1/common-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.2.1/common-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.jar'.
            > No such host is known (jcenter.bintray.com)
   > Could not download transform-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download jetifier-processor.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-alpha10)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-alpha10/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-alpha10.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-alpha10/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-alpha10.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download asm-analysis.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:6.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/6.0/asm-analysis-6.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/6.0/asm-analysis-6.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download asm-commons.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/6.0/asm-commons-6.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/6.0/asm-commons-6.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download asm-util.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm-util:6.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/6.0/asm-util-6.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/6.0/asm-util-6.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download asm-tree.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/6.0/asm-tree-6.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/6.0/asm-tree-6.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download asm.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jopt-simple.jar (net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download proguard-gradle.jar (net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.5.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.5.0/bundletool-0.5.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.5.0/bundletool-0.5.0.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download jetifier-core.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-alpha10)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-alpha10/jetifier-core-1.0.0-alpha10.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-alpha10/jetifier-core-1.0.0-alpha10.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.2.1/builder-model-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.2.1/builder-model-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.2.1/protos-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.2.1/protos-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.2.1/apkzlib-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.2.1/apkzlib-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.2.1/apksig-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.2.1/apksig-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download javawriter.jar (com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download bcpkix-jdk15on.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download bcprov-jdk15on.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download fastutil.jar (it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download json-simple.jar (com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.2.1/annotations-26.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.2.1/annotations-26.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download protobuf-java-util.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.4.0/protobuf-java-util-3.4.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.4.0/protobuf-java-util-3.4.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jimfs.jar (com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:23.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download httpmime.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download httpclient.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download httpcore.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.2.1/databinding-common-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.2.1/databinding-common-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.1/baseLibrary-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.1/baseLibrary-3.2.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download antlr4.jar (org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download commons-io.jar (commons-io:commons-io:2.4)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download juniversalchardet.jar (com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download javapoet.jar (com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download kotlin-stdlib.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.71)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download proguard-base.jar (net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:6.0.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/6.0.3/proguard-base-6.0.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/6.0.3/proguard-base-6.0.3.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download auto-value.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download error_prone_annotations.jar (com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download protobuf-java.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jdom2.jar (org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download commons-compress.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download javax.inject.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download kxml2.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jsr305.jar (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download j2objc-annotations.jar (com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download animal-sniffer-annotations.jar (org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download commons-logging.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download kotlin-stdlib-common.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.2.71)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.71.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.71.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download annotations.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download javax.activation.jar (com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jaxb-runtime.jar (org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jaxb-core.jar (org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.2.11)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.2.11/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar'.
```

'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/2.21/istack-commons-runtime-2.21.jar'.

> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/2.21/istack-commons-runtime-2.21.jar'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 59s
  Command: C:\Users\IB\Desktop\Android\myapp\berry_networks\Dart test\Scaffold\intro_to_scaffold\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)`
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. With similar error as displayed by you. But later I found out the issue was related to internet connection. Please check your internet and try it again this should work.